# ARC Ready XML Parser

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

Ok I just tried to use 3 different xml parsers like TBXML and others. Does anybody know an arc ready xml parser. I tried to convert the files to make them arc ready but its not working correctly, as the process creates new errors. Also to disable the ARC mechanism for the specific files does not work for me.

Is there any XML parser out there, that is not older than 2 years?

Cheers

Comment: Does [`NSXMLParser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) qualify?..

Comment: Yeah, using apple's parser seems logical.

Comment: I'll give it a try. At least the code should be up to date.

Comment: @mogio Being up to date is the least of its advantages. More importantly, it is thoroughly tested, well-documented, and comes with lots of examples and articles on the net.

Comment: okay.... to handle the NSXMLParser is just way to heavy stuff for me. I couldn't believe my eyes how much effort is involved to just create an array with some data that comes from an xml file. Actually I don't even know what the NSXMLParser does apart from reconizing the end and the start of an element. I expected that at least it would be possible to create a dicionary from a prefered tag automatically. Something that would include sub elements as key objects or something like that. Also I cannot find one useful complete example of how you connect to a server to get the xml for final parsing.

Comment: In other languages this is pretty simple stuff. First time I really see myself giving up with something. Kind of sad.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for that too, and I found [KissXML](https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML).

It's last update was 2 years ago, but it was to convert it to ARC.

I've been using TBXML, but it's not ARC-compatible, and I don't want to have memory leaks because of it, so I'm planning to replace it with KissXML and see how it goes.